# HTML 5 Validation fails for "Attribute addthis:url not allowed on element a at this point."

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a web page where I use **ShareThis plugin** to show share count of different posts. My website is a MVC4 Project. The code is like:

```
    @{
        string strShareThisURL = "addthis:url=\"" + mainURL +"/"+ strBlopUrl+"\"";
         <div class="share">
            @Html.Raw(strShareThisHTML)
        </div>                   
    }
```

It is rendered like:

```
<div class="share">
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
   <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style" url="http://192.168.1.50:8082/blogpost/test-centers/2014/05/21/did-you-know-these-people" href="#" style="display: inline-block;"><a class="atc_s addthis_button_compact"><span></span></a><a class="addthis_button_expanded" target="_blank" title="View more services" href="#" tabindex="1000"></a></a><div class="atclear"></div></div>
</div>
```

I am getting following error:

```
Attribute addthis:url not allowed on element a at this point.
```

Please let me know what should I do to skipp this HTML Validation error?

Thanks

Comment: The HTML code in the “It is rendered like:” part causes some validation errors, but not the one mentioned in the question. It has a `url` attribute, which is not valid in any version of HTML, and it has nested `a` elements, which are not valid either.

Answer (score 1):

I just found solution to this problem. The solution was to replace **addthis:url** with **data-url** and rebind the attribute on document.ready event. see code below:

```
@{
    string strShareThisURL = "data-url=\"" + mainURL +"/"+ strBlopUrl+"\"";
     <div class="share">
        @Html.Raw(strShareThisHTML)
    </div>                   
}
```

Javascript code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        try {
            $('.addthis_counter').each(function () {
                try {
                    if ($(this).is("[data-url]")) {
                        $(this).attr("addthis:url", $(this).attr("data-url"));
                    }
                }
                catch (er) { }
            });
        } catch (err) { }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to solve this problem where **addthis:url** is not passing the HTML Validation.

I have tried to change the attribute to **data-url** but it won't solve the problem. This changing is only passing the HTML Validation while the plugin script is working with **addthis:url** attribute.

So it would be better to not include the **addthis:url** attribute in the anchor element "`<a>`" but to insert it after the page is loaded using a jquery script like:

```
$(window).load(function(){setTimeout(function(){"path_to_your_script"}, 100);});
```

Then use the following code in your script:

```
$(".addthis_counter").attr("addthis:url", \"" + mainURL +"/"+ strBlopUrl+"\"");
```

With this modification you can pass the HTML validation since it won't throw the error because *no addthis:url in the anchor element* but the plugin will still work as *the attribute is exist on the loaded page*.